make https//mysite locally (redirect to localhost through hosts) secured
I configured my hosts file and netsch interface so the call to url https://test.mywebsite return https://localhost:3000.
Now, Chrome reacts properly when I call localhost, but when I call mywebsite, it still tells me that my url is not secured. The exact message (with translation):
This server could not prove that it is test.mywebsite. Its security certificate is from localhost. Possible reasons are a bad configuration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
I generated certificates for both *.mywebsite.com and localhost. I added the exact url of mywebsite.com to google  chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure, without any success...
It says actually that my certificate is not valid, but I don't know why (i generated it 30min ago, it is valid until 2026)

You have to install the generated certificate as trusted root CA certificate into your system's trust store (Chrome used the system store).

We don't know what's in your certificate and your question doesn't help. test.mywebsite does not match *.mywebsite.com. It does match *.mywebsite. Specific details like that matter. But those are placeholders most likely.
